# Kubernetes, NGINX: How to get fixed outgoing IP for Pods to whitelist them in external services

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

How can I get a fixed IP for Pods to whitelist them in external service.

I have configured the Nginx Controller as loadbalancer and it has a fixed external IP, but the Pods seems to have not the same IP or change it during the routing process, so I can not white list them in specific services.

What's the way to go to archive this?

Comment: pods usually have private ips, how would you whitelist private ips in an external service?

Comment: You would also never want them to have fixed IP's as the get killed and recreated or the scale etc, fixing ip's is not dynamic or scalable

Comment: Yes that's why it's hard to understand how to solve this problem. For example when I want to use an external service which only allows connections for a given IP. I can not change this because the external service is owned by another company. What to do here? What's the best practice for this?

Comment: so far, I found this: https://github.com/nirmata/kube-static-egress-ip
I will check it out...

Comment: https://github.com/nirmata/kube-static-egress-ip was not working for me.

I am using GKE, so another possible solutions is Cloud NAT:

`This gateway can be used with a GKE cluster, which provides a stable public egress IP to all the pods inside it, which enables them to be whitelisted by third party service providers.

The example implementation for using Cloud NAT with GKE is provided here ` https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual Answer:

Solution 1: Was not working for me, as I don't know how to assign external IPs to the CR.
https://github.com/nirmata/kube-static-egress-ip

Solution 2: Cloud NAT
https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview